# Waterfall chart (waterfalls package) ggplot - wrapping long x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-wrap, axis-labels

Using the waterfalls package.
If I try to wrap long axis labels, the labels do wrap, but then they are arranged alphabetically, independently of the data.

Data:

```
structure(list(Factors = c("Start", "Differential A", "Move", 
"EQ", "Differential (Premium)", "Transportation"), Cost = c(119.19, 
-25.4, -0.832, -5.7, 4.93, -7.37)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Without wrapping:

```
library(waterfalls)
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, 
  total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + 
labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL)
```

[image: without wrapping]

With str_wrap:

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, 
    total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + 
  labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))
```

Scale for x is already present.
Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.

[image: Alphabetized axis labels]

I've also tried wrap_format with the same result.

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, 
    total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + 
  labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the labels before your `waterfall` function:

```r
library(waterfalls)
library(tidyverse)

wf <- data.frame(factors = c('Start',
                             'Differential A',
                             'Move',
                             'EQ',
                             'Differential (Premium)',
                             'Transportation'),
                 cost = c(119.19, -25.4, -0.832, -5.7, 4.93, -7.37))


wf %>%
  mutate(factors = str_wrap(factors, width = 10)) %>%
  waterfall(calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE,
            total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + 
  labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you.